Getting a reference to thermal_zone0 always returns an error pointer
I am trying to write a simple Linux kernel module to read the temperature from the thermal_zone0 of my RaspberryPi 4B running RaspberryPi OS 64-bit. I can always do cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp to get the temperature however, I want to do this from the kernel module only since I want to learn writing kernel modules.
Here is my simple code:
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/thermal.h>

static int __init my_module_init(void)
{
    struct thermal_zone_device *thermal_zone;
    thermal_zone = thermal_zone_get_zone_by_name("thermal_zone0");
    if (!thermal_zone) {
        pr_err("Failed to get thermal zone 0\n");
        return -ENODEV;
    }

    if(thermal_zone->ops->get_temp)  // <-- gives segmentation fault on loading
        pr_info("Get temp is defined");

    return 0;
}

static void __exit my_module_exit(void)
{
    pr_info("Module unloaded\n");
}

module_init(my_module_init);
module_exit(my_module_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Your Name");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Example kernel module to interact with thermal_zone0");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");


The code to read the temperature has been deleted as the temperature is always being read as zero. The reason behind that is thermal_zone is an error pointer and I verified that by trying to dereference it.
My question is how can I get a reference to thermal_zone0 and read its temperature??
I tried looking at the kernel config if the thermal module is enabled and it is enabled
..
CONFIG_THERMAL = y
..
CONFIG_THERMAL_HWMON = y
..
Broadcom thermal drivers
CONFIG_BCM2711_THERMAL=y
..
Also, the temperature is being read correctly when I do cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp and hence expecting the given code to work

thermal_zone_get_zone_by_name() returns a negated errno value on error, so you need to replace if (!thermal_zone) { with if (IS_ERR(thermal_zone)) {. You could replace the return -ENODEV; in the if block with return PTR_ERR(thermal_zone); to propagate the error code from thermal_zone_get_zone_by_name().

So I got the answer after looking at the the other thermal drivers' code.
The name of the thermal zone is contained in the file /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type
Doing a cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/type gave the output cpu-thermal.
So now, the code changes to
...
thermal_zone = thermal_zone_get_zone_by_name("cpu-thermal");
...

And that's it!
